# Scrapy 204 no data received

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use Scrapy to crawl web data, it response debug 204 and debug 'no data received!' I have used this code to crawl many data, but it doesn't work this time. I don't know why.

The code and feedback are below.

```
class SoccerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'soccer'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa']

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'.*/startseite/wettbewerb/.*'))
        print(tags)
        for tag in tags[:14]:
            url = re.findall(r'https://www.transfermarkt.com/.+', response.urljoin(tag.get('href')))
            if len(url) == 0:
                continue
            else:
                yield scrapy.Request(url[0], callback=self.parse1, dont_filter=True)
```

The feedback is below:

```
2019-05-01 17:16:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (204) <GET https://www.transfermarkt.com/robots.txt> (referer: http://www.web.cn/)
2019-05-01 17:16:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (204) <GET https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa> (referer: http://www.web.cn/)
2019-05-01 17:16:38 [chardet.universaldetector] DEBUG: no data received!
2019-05-01 17:16:38 [chardet.universaldetector] DEBUG: no data received!
```

The setting header is as below

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'host': 'www.web.cn',
    'Referer': 'http://www.web.cn/',
    'Cookie': 'is cookis'
}
```

Comment: The tag returns [ ], so the step can't go to pars1() method

Comment: Can you update your question accordingly? Because your comment sounds like a response to your current question.

Comment: The response is no data received, and it is DEBUG  crawl 204,  so I don't know why this happen